# Find height of parent view

Tags: android, imageview, android-custom-view

I am creating a custom imageview and I am trying to find the height of the parent. The only detail I know about the parent is that it would potentially scroll. The reason I need the parent's height is because I am trying to figure out the imageview's position on the screen. I have made an equation that works for accurately calculating its position, but it only works when I manually enter in the parents height. Is there any way to retrieve this information or is there another way to get my imageview's position on the screen every time it changes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this way

```
public class MyImageView extends ImageView {


    int parentHeight;
    int parentWidth;

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public MyImageView(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }





    @Override
    protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {

        if(((View)this.getParent()).getMeasuredWidth()!=0){
            parentHeight = ((View)this.getParent()).getMeasuredHeight();
            parentWidth = ((View)this.getParent()).getMeasuredWidth();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like it is working, how can I confirm that its returning the correct value?